# Using "source" command to fetch variables giving unexpected output

Tags: php, bash, debian

I'm setting up a script that uses variables from another script.

Script 1 has the variables

Script 2 sources script 1 and output an unexpected error.

Fresh Debian 9 install via GCP.

1.sh

```
1="test"
2="test2"
3="test3"
```

2.sh

```
source 1.sh
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

Running 2.sh, I expected:

```
test
test2
test3
```

But I received:

```
1.sh: line 2: 1=test: command not found
1.sh: line 3: 2=test2: command not found
1.sh: line 4: 3=test3: command not found
#empty line#
#empty line#
#empty line#
```

[This link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) is telling me that's how a bash variable is declared.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: But the link lies on how a variable name must look like to be assigned in this way.  Did you ever trie `1="test"`manually in your bash? You will also get a _command not found_ error. You can't set positional parameters like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1`, `2`, and `3` are not valid variable names. `$1` etc are used to access the arguments passed to a script, but they cannot be assigned to like normal variables. Try using something like `var1="test"` etc instead.

Also, I recommend adding a shebang line (e.g. `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) to the beginning of 2.sh. It doesn't matter for 1.sh, since `source`ing a script doesn't pay attention to shebang lines.

Oh, and I forgot another thing: when you use a variable (or parameter, or whatever), you should almost always put double-quotes around it (e.g. use `echo "$var1"` instead of just `echo $var1`). When you use a variable without double-quotes, the shell will try to parse it in ways that are more likely to cause trouble than to help.

And finally: especially when you're starting out, try pasting your scripts into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) -- it's good at spotting common scripting mistakes, and can point them out before they become bad habbits.

Comment: You're a legend.